# Install R in my own directory

Tags: software-installation, non-root-user

How can I install a new version of R in my own directory, e.g., `/local/data/project/behi`.

Comment: You might be able to do so by starting from source; but if you have to ask, I'd guess yu aren't up to doing so. Please tell us _what_ system you are running, and _why_ you are interested in a new version.

Comment: Version specific installation using source code is much different than the installation using YUM or APT. It depends on OS version and the number of dependencies that need to be met for the installation to complete successfully. I have documented the installation of R 3.3.3 on SLES11 SP3 in http://hashprompt.blogspot.com/2017/06/installation-of-r-on-suse-linux.html Hope that it might help you install on linux systems.

Answer (score 58):

The easiest way to do this is to install R [from source](http://cran.rstudio.com):

```
$ wget http://cran.rstudio.com/src/base/R-3/R-3.4.1.tar.gz
$ tar xvf R-3.4.1.tar.gz
$ cd R-3.4.1
$ ./configure --prefix=$HOME/R
$ make && make install
```

The second-to-last step is the critical one.  It configures R to be installed into a subdirectory of your own home directory.

To run it on Linux, macOS and similar systems, add `$HOME/R/bin` to your `PATH`. Then, shell commands like `R` and `Rscript` will work.

On macOS, you have another alternative: [build `R.app`](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-admin.html#Building-R_002eapp) and install it into your user's private `Applications` folder. You need to have Xcode installed to do this.

You might consider giving `--prefix=$HOME` instead. That installs R at the top level of your home directory, so that the `R` and `Rscript` binaries end up in `$HOME/bin`, which is likely already in your user's `PATH`. The downside is that it makes later uninstallation harder, since R would be intermingled among your other `$HOME` contents.

(If this is the first thing you've installed to `$HOME/bin`, you might have to log out and back in to get this in your `PATH`, since it's often added conditionally only if `$HOME/bin` exists at login time.)

This general pattern applies to a large amount of Unix software you can install from source code. If the software has a `configure` script, it probably understands the `--prefix` option, and if not, there is usually some alternative with the same effect.

These features are common for a number of reasons. In decreasing order of likelihood, in my experience:

- The safe default (`/usr/local`) is not the right `$prefix` in all situations. Circumstances might dictate something else such as `/usr`, `/opt/$PKGNAME`, etc.
- Binary package building systems ([RPM](http://rpm.org/), [DEB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deb_(file_format)), [PKG](https://wiki.freebsd.org/pkgng), [Cygport](https://cygwinports.github.io/cygport/toc_index.html)...) typically build and install the package into a special staging directory, then pack that up in such a way that it expands into the desired installation location.
- Your case, where you can't get `root` to install the software into a typical location, so you install into `$HOME` instead.

Comment: I would recommend `./configure --prefix=$HOME/R --enable-R-shlib` to make sure you compile R shared library. Otherwise, RStudio will complain.

Comment: Didn't work me. Script ended with `configure: error: --with-readline=yes (default) and headers/libs are not available
make: *** No targets specified and no makefile found.  Stop.`

Comment: @ApproachingDarknessFish: That has nothing to do with this question or my answer. You're missing necessary prerequisites for building R on your system with your chosen options. Specifically here, you're missing the readline development libraries. If you have more problems, post a new question.

Answer (score 9):

You can also use the wrapper application [Renv](https://github.com/viking/Renv).

*excerpt*

> #### Simple R Version Management: Renv
>
> Renv lets you easily switch between multiple versions of R. It's simple,
>   unobtrusive, and follows
>   the UNIX tradition of single-purpose tools that do one thing well.
>
> Renv does…
>
> - Let you change the global R version on a per-user basis.
> - Provide support for per-project R versions.
> - Allow you to override the R version with an environment variable.

Answer (score 1):

Build from source with `./configure --prefix=/local/data/project/behi ; make ; make install`

If you're installing from an RPM package and it was created relocatable, you could use

```
rpm ... --prefix /local/data/project/behi
```

But not all packages are built with relocatable binaries, and I don't think debian packages have this option (although you might succeed with `dpkg --instdir`).