# install and run new version of R

Tags: r

an old version of R is already installed on the server I am working with, but it is not really useful for my work. I have tried to install R 3.1.1 on my own directory (/local/data/project/behi) on the server using this command :

$ wget http://cran.rstudio.com/src/base/R-3/R-3.1.1.tar.gz
$ tar xvf R-3.1.1.tar.gz
$ cd R-3.1.1
$ ./configure --prefix=$HOME/R
$ make && make install

when I tried to run R (by just typing R in my directory) again it showed me the old version of R. would somebody please let me know what the problem is and how I can **install** and **run** the new version of R?

thanks in advance,
Behi

Comment: See this part of [the answer from last time you asked](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/149451/install-r-in-my-own-directory): "To run it, add `$HOME/R/R.framework/Versions/Current/Resources/bin` to your `PATH`. Then, commands like R and Rscript will work.". That is, `export PATH="$HOME/R/R.framework/Versions/Current/Resources/bin:$PATH"`.

Comment: Hi Michael, thanks for your comments. since I am biologist I have some problems in such issues.

Comment: You can either use that `export` in run scripts for your R stuff, put it in `$HOME/.profile`, or use a strategy from here: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/124444/how-can-i-cleanly-add-to-path  If other people on the system are expected to use what you are doing you'll have to go with run scripts.