# cannot export environment path to configure script

Tags: compiling, environment-variables, configure

I'm trying to compile `R-3.4.1` on a server I have access to (but not root access). The script compilation fails because of `zlib` version. I follow the instruction [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/343452/how-to-install-r-3-3-1-in-my-own-directory), and I compile `zilb` and it is available in the path `/storage/users/<uname>/trm/zlib/lib` I tried to add this path to both `$LD_LIBRARY_PATH` and to $LIBRARY_PATH$ and it doesn't work. I also tried, as per the link above to run the `configure` as following:

```
$ ./configure --prefix=/storage/users/<uname>/trm/R LDFLAGS="-L/storage/users/<uname>/trm/zlib/lib"
```

but the error remains. The configure script itself doesn't have the bug mentioned in the link above. Sadly, I don't know what is the distro on the server. Clearly, I'm missing something, but I don't know what.

---

edit 1

These are the final lines of the `./configure` command

```
checking zlib.h usability... yes
checking zlib.h presence... yes
checking for zlib.h... yes
checking if zlib version >= 1.2.5... no
checking whether zlib support suffices... configure: error: zlib library and headers are required
```

(I tried this with @PSkocik suggestion)

also, to confirm, I copy paste the path I used for the `configure` command into `ls`:

```
libz.a  libz.so  libz.so.1  libz.so.1.2.11  pkgconfig
```

---

Edit 2
Following @AmeyaVS instructions, I post here the content of `zlib.pc`

```
prefix=/storage/users/<uname>/trm/zlib
exec_prefix=${prefix}
libdir=${exec_prefix}/lib
sharedlibdir=${libdir}
includedir=${prefix}/include

Name: zlib
Description: zlib compression library
Version: 1.2.11

Requires:
Libs: -L${libdir} -L${sharedlibdir} -lz
Cflags: -I${includedir}
```

Comment: *"The script compilation fails because of zlib version"* what is the complete error message? I suspect you will need to supply the header file *include path* (perhaps via `CFLAGS`), not only the library path. BTW did you mean `R-3.4.1`?

Comment: Try `LDFLAGS="-L/storage/users/<uname>/trm/zlib/lib" ./configure --prefix=/storage/users/<uname>/trm/R`, that'll definitely set the environment variable. Your version will only do that if the configure script will cooperate.

Comment: @steeldriver, I added the final lines of the ``configure`` command. You are are right about the version number, I fixed that.

Comment: @PSkocik, I tried with your suggestion and still no go

Answer (score 1):

You need to provide the `configure` script with the pkg-config script path of the `zlib` library.

Here is what I usually do when building `GNU Autotools` libraries:

```
# First unzip the files from the library zipped file.
tar xvf zlib-1.2.11.tar.gz
cd zlib-1.2.11
# if it has **configure** script in the source directory
mkdir objdir
cd objdir
# Set this environment variable from where you want to install the library.
# export ZLIB_HOME=<path where you want to install zlib>
export ZLIB_HOME=$HOME/apps/zlib
../configure --prefix=$ZLIB_HOME
# Build the library
make
# Install the library
make install
# Set the PKG_CONFIG_PATH if PKG_CONFIG_PATH is not set for pkgconfig to locate the build flags for the library.
export PKG_CONFIG_PATH=$ZLIB_HOME/lib/pkgconfig
# or use this in-case the PKG_CONFIG_PATH is not empty:
# export PKG_CONFIG_PATH=$PKG_CONFIG_PATH:$ZLIB_HOME/lib/pkgconfig
```

Now try configuring the `R` package within the same terminal session.

**Note:**
What I usually do is add the environment variable for the library in my `$HOME/.bashrc`(***assuming you are using bash shell, kindly find the respective file for your terminal session***) file like this for the library to be persistent for newer installation of other packages requiring this library:

```
export ZLIB_HOME=$HOME/apps/zlib
# Assuming LD_LIBRARY_PATH is already populated.
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:$ZLIB_HOME/lib
# Assuming PKG_CONFIG_PATH is already populated.
export PKG_CONFIG_PATH=$PKG_CONFIG_PATH:$ZLIB_HOME/lib/pkgconfig
```

**Update:**
You can find the version and the include path specified for any library using following commands:

```
# Check module/library version
# pkg-config --modversion <library_name>
pkg-config --modversion zlib
# Check compiler include flag for the specified library.
# pkg-config --cflags <library_name>
pkg-config --cflags zlib
```

If you are getting `zlib` version as `1.2.11` and the gcc include path as
`-I/storage/users/<uname>/trm/zlib/include` and still the configure script for `R` reports the `zlib` version as `1.2.5` then most probably the configure script is looking for the dependent library at very specified location.

Comment: I didn't understand the ``objdir`` creation part. I create an empty folder and I enter and there is nothing compile there. I skipped this part, and recompiled the files, I added the ``PKG_CONFIG_PATH``  part and ended up with the same result.

Comment: objdir is for building the code out of source tree build operation. I ran the `../configure` script from the source directory of the zlib library source directory. In-case you are still getting the error kindly cleanup the source directory with extra files generated during the configure step.

Comment: Hi, I removed the folder, and untared the source again and followed your instructions with the exception of putting the ``zlib`` path at the end and not the beginning  of the ``LD_LIBRARY_PATH`` since I already have an older version of ``zlib`` installed on that machine. It still doesn't work

Comment: Clean up the `R` configure script output also. It is better to build the source out of the source tree in a separate directory. Also post the contents of the `zlib.pc` contained in the zlib `lib/pkconfig` directory.

Comment: I got the same result after using a fresh ``untar`` of ``R`` with the same result. I posted also the content of ``zlib.pc`` in my original question.

Comment: Add the `zlib` path before the system library path for both `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` and `PKG_CONFIG_PATH`. I will update once I get back on my system.

Comment: I did, both before and after, no luck.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/62769/discussion-between-ameyavs-and-yotam).