# Local installation of pcre2 not detected while installing R 4.0.4 from source

Tags: software-installation, r, pcre

I am trying to do a build and local install of R 4.0.4 on Red Hat Linux 6.8. There were several unmet dependencies which I resolved by doing local installations (following the procedure in [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/343452/how-to-install-r-3-3-1-in-my-own-directory)). However, I couldn't resolve the issue of `pcre2` with that procedure. This is the configure command I run:

```
./configure --with-pcre2 --prefix=$HOME/bin/R-4.0.4 --enable-R-shlib LDFLAGS="-L/$HOME/local/zlib-1.2.11/lib -L/$HOME/local/bzip2-1.0.8/lib -L/$HOME/local/xz-5.2.5/lib -L/$HOME/local/pcre2-10.00/lib" CPPFLAGS="-I/$HOME/local/zlib-1.2.11/include"
```

This is the error I get:

```
checking whether PCRE support suffices... no
configure: error: PCRE2 library and headers are required, or use --with-pcre1 and PCRE >= 8.32 with UTF-8 support
```

I also tried configure with a local installation of `pcre-8.44` and `--with-pcre1` flag but I get the same error.

What should I do so that the configure script detects the `pcre2` local installation?

Answer (score 5):

I solved my problem like this:

1. `wget https://github.com/PCRE2Project/pcre2/releases/download/pcre2-10.42/pcre2-10.42.tar.gz`
2. `tar -zxvf pcre2-10.42.tar.gz`
3. `cd pcre2-10.42`
4. `./configure`
5. `make -j 24`
6. `sudo make install`

I am using Ubuntu 20.04 and R version 4.1.0

Comment: https://github.com/PCRE2Project/pcre2/releases/download/pcre2-10.42/pcre2-10.42.tar.gz

Answer (score 2):

Try

`sudo apt install libpcre2-posix2 libpcre2-dev`

Comment: simply `sudo apt install libpcre2-dev` did the trick for me on Linux Mint

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem and the solution turned out to be that R's ./configure needed the pcre2-config program to be in my PATH.  So, this should solve it:

```
PATH="${PATH}:/$HOME/local/pcre2-10.00/bin" ./configure --with-pcre2 --prefix=$HOME/bin/R-4.0.4 --enable-R-shlib LDFLAGS="-L/$HOME/local/zlib-1.2.11/lib -L/$HOME/local/bzip2-1.0.8/lib -L/$HOME/local/xz-5.2.5/lib -L/$HOME/local/pcre2-10.00/lib" CPPFLAGS="-I/$HOME/local/zlib-1.2.11/include"
```

Answer (score 1):

I installed R version 4.1.0 and solved this problem using:

`./configure --prefix=/usr/lusers/mingy16/R-4.1.0 --with-pcre1`

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and resolved it by installing the "pcre2-devel" package. I had pcre and pcre-devel packages, which worked for R 3.x as well as the pcre2 package, but the required "pcre2-devel" wasn't installed by default.

Comment: Thanks, can you please tell me how to install the pcre2-devel package? I couldn't find any source for that. Is it included in pcre2 source?

Comment: I only had to run "yum install pcre2-devel" but it's present in the "rhel-7-server-optional-rpms" repository on my machine. I'm not sure what the repository for RHEL 6.8 is but you could review the repositories in /etc/yum.repos.d/redhat.repo and set "enabled=true" for the optional RPMS repository. 

You may want to shoot in the dark and try "yum install --enable-repo=rhel-6-server-optional-rpms pcre2-devel"

Comment: The only problem is I don't have sudo permissions. That's why I was doing local installs of the dependencies. Do you have any other suggestions?