# Error in readRDS("file.rds") : error reading from connection Execution halted

Tags: linux, r

I am unable to read an rds file into R via my remote server. I am able to read it into R on Rstudio, but it will not work when using my remote server. It was working previously, but R on the server may have updated.

I get the error message below when I run my code with all my programs, and when I only try reading in the object.

```
my-remote-server-user:~$ Rscript code/test-readRDS.R
Error in readRDS("/home/data/file.rds") : 
  error reading from connection
Execution halted
```

The R on the remote server is R-4.2.2, but the rds file was made with R-3.6.1, so I tried to install that version of R instead. I tried following the instructions here ([x](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/149451/install-r-in-my-own-directory)) to install R-3.6.1, but it did not work. R.Version() still says 4.2.2. Since I am on a remote server with others, I cannot change the version of R for everyone, and I can't add my own version in my folder either. Is there any other option?